# Swift 2 SwiftyJSON API data to UITableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swifty-json

My app should show **product title** / **price** / **product images** / **product description** and it fetches the data in JSON format using *Alamofire* and *SwiftyJSON* and show it in a UITableview.

The link to the JSON data is: https://www.spree.co.za/api/v1/catalog/browse/2641

There is loads of other info as well which I dont need. How would I save for eg. the "title", "imageURL", "Size" in arrays?

This is my code which I used to get the "titles"

var productTitles = JSON

```
func getJsonData(){
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.spree.co.za/api/v1/catalog/browse/2641").responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        //Check if the result have value
        if let value = response.result.value {

            let json = JSON(value)
            let objects = (json["products"])

            //While Loop
            var x = 0
            while x < objects.count {
                self.productTitles.append(objects[x]["title"])
                x++
            }

            //Test
            print(self.productTitles[3])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
func getTitlesFromJson(data: AnyObject?) -> [String] {
    guard data != nil else {
        return []
    }
    let json = JSON(data!)

    var titles: [String] = []
    for (_, subJson): (String, JSON) in json["products"] {
        if let title = subJson["title"].string {
            titles.append(title)
        }
    }
    return titles
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Alamofire.request(...).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

    //Check for error
    ...

    let titles = getTitlesFromJson(response.result.value)

    // Other actions
    ...

}
```

Other arrays is done similarly